# PFLoginViewController in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to use `PFLoginViewController` in Parse/Swift.  My code is posted below.  It builds successfully but my simulator screen is blank.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, PFLogInViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var logInController = PFLogInViewController()
        logInController.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(logInController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        logInController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
            | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
            | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
            | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
            | PFLogInFields.DismissButton)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Am I missing something that's necessary to view the LogIn screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't present a view controller inside `viewDidLoad`. If you want to do it straight away then put that code into `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Also, set the fields before presenting it.

Like this...

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    var logInController = PFLogInViewController()
    logInController.delegate = self
    logInController.fields = (PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword
        | PFLogInFields.LogInButton
        | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton
        | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten
        | PFLogInFields.DismissButton)

    self.presentViewController(logInController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks I put it in viewDidAppear() and it worked.  When is it better to use viewWillAppear() instead?

Comment: With `DidAppear` you will see your view controller appear and then you'll see the login transition. With `willAppear` you will not see the view controller appear. You'll just see the login view appear.

Comment: @SmoothOperator This is just iOS stuff. It's the same with Objective-C or Swift. You're welcome though :) remember to up vote and accept if an answer solves your problem. :)

Comment: I created a subclass of PFLogin and couldn't get the fields to change, only I that worked was logInView!.dismissButton?.hidden = true - works as expected using the normal class, so the code was correct.